# Narrow the type based on what kind of property other object parameter has

Tags: typescript

We are trying to make a database layer for the MongoDB and we would like to use type system to avoid conflicting parameters. Each document (MSite, MOrganization etc.) have `users` and/or `machines`. We would like to have the API, so that the `field` would have correct options based on what kind of group is given.

For example, if `MRegion` doesn't have machines, but it has `users`, `MSite` has both, etc. When `match` has `{ sites: Array<any> }` then `field` should be `sites`.

```
export type MGroup = MSite | MOrganization | MRegion | MDistributor | MSystem

export async function insertRelation<
  T extends MRelation
>({
  match,
  field,
  relation,
}: {
  match: Filter<MGroup> & { type: string; _id: string }
  field: 'users' | 'machines'
  relation: Omit<T, AutomatedProperties>
}): Promise<void> {
  ...function body...
}
```

I have tried two approaches: [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), but I never got the types right as there were errors inside the function which means that the types were not the same anymore.

All help would be appreciated!

```
// more complex type comes from MongoDB
type Filter<T> = {
}

type MSite = {
    parent: string
    type: "site"
    users: Array<any>
    machines: Array<any>
}

type MOrganization = {
    parent: string
    type: "organization"
    users: Array<any>
    machines: Array<any>
}

type MRegion = {
    parent: string
    type: "region"
    users: Array<any>
}

type MDistributor = {
    parent: string
    type: "distributor"
    users: Array<any>
}

type MSystem = {
    type: "system"
}

export type MGroup = MSite | MOrganization | MRegion | MDistributor | MSystem

export async function insertRelation({
  match,
  field,
}: {
  match: Filter<MGroup> & { type: string; _id: string }
  field: 'users' | 'machines'
}): Promise<void> {
}

// should give an error
await insertRelation({ match: { type: 'distributor', _id: 'test' }, field: 'machines' })
```

Simplied example [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFsHsCcFNQMaXABwDawB6gC4E8V4lxYBnUAM2mVAFlIA7Ac0gBEAhAKH0NADEAlmhyxoAHgAqAPlABeUAG9OAX07cC8WgGUBIuYs6gjoFAEM4DHAC5QpHNAHNDxnrBsAiUrtjvnRgK6koqQ2AILQ0KZ4YqYMeFJ+EKYIABaOZGERUTFxCarqvLQA8tBMsQIAXqY4Aoz6SsYm5rCWNnYOTo2uHjBlDJXVtQy+jYHBmZHRsfGJ4MlpDBmg4ZM5M-mudABKsExD9YlmFta29o5Mid2g7nB7jCPGY9Ahy1lTuSpqm7SsAu0CACN-DgYAdGkcWid-p0XBoPAATP5nIEg6APAJBZ4TbLTPJfDR0LR4OywcBg2GEDykYkicC+fJYFAwHC4Am0ADi1H8KH02m8oAAPnQSn0BjU6kLaDs7gxBXRfv8UaDJUSSeA1IzmaBTNSGAhKP49eLZY5MTgdmhBowABQNJI4VIAGmcFAEsDQ8OdyhsdrmDpSNkEwlEYg5XJQMgAZIpWZTTh0mABuUAAfQE8LaZ2YoFURld7ozoAA5E9SEW5UW5ql0mWVABKGwABWo4D+sDEADdIOmZEp8iBbClIP4PaA9h34LFQKJqNBOKYAO6mXSgU2ic3uq0MW321I+2NuYuIxXAmBFx2p9M2IsiOzl5QX-Me69VhZke91oA)

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] which demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  Right now you've got a bunch of undeclared types like `MSite`, etc. and so I hit errors before I can even start trying to work on it.  If you make it easy to get started it's more likely that I can give a solution that works.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the feedback, Playground link added

Comment: Please also place the example as plain text in the question itself; an external link is a great supplement but isn't sufficient for SO.

Comment: Hmm, your `Filter<T>` is empty.  Is there something `Filter<MGroup> & ...` should be enforcing? If so, you should add that to the `Filter<T>` definition in the example.  If not, you should remove `Filter` entirely from the example since it's not doing anything but being distracting.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPpgzW) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining, after you fix up the question as per my previous two comments.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: The type for the Filter is a complex one from MongoDB, but we add that the filter should always contain `type` and `_id`. I left the Filter type as we do need to use that Filter's generic type

Comment: When you say "we do need to use that Filter's generic type", presumably you mean in your actual code.  But you don't need it in this example, or else you would have given it a type that does something.  If `type Filter<T> = {}` then `T` is [completely ignored and is confusing at best](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--).  It is distracting. Please remove it from your example code like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nl2llW), or give it some structural dependence on `T`.